# Crop an image using UIBezierPath - Beginner

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibezierpath, croppic

I have a shape defined in `UIBezierPath` . I also have an `UIImage`. I now want to crop this image using `UIBezierPath`. How can I do this ?

```
let shape = UIBezierPath(rect: imageRect)

let image = UIImage(cgimage: c)
```

Comment: Still no luck. Anyone with a solution ?

Comment: is Objc Code ok for you ?

Comment: Is my solution is helpful to you ? or  you have still issue with my solution  ?

Answer (score 0):

I am putting `Objective C` code. However it is easy to convert in `swift3`

Please try below code

```
CAShapeLayer *newLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
newLayer.path = self.shape.CGPath;


[self.view.layer setMask:newLayer];

CGRect rectToCrop = self.shape.bounds;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);//, NO, 0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[newLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
newLayer = nil;

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rectToCrop);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.imgVPhoto.image.scale orientation:self.imgVPhoto.image.imageOrientation];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

And then save

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

    //saving cut Image
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(croppedImage);

    if (imgData) {

        NSString *imagePath = 

        if([FileUtility fileExistsAtFilePath:imagePath]) {
            [FileUtility deleteFile:imagePath];
        }

        //need to add this task in BG to avoid blocking of main thread

        [imgData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:true];

    }

}];
```

Hope it helps to you

**EDIT**

**SWIFT Convert**

```
var newLayer = CAShapeLayer()
newLayer.path = shape.cgPath
view.layer.mask = newLayer
var rectToCrop: CGRect = shape.bounds
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
//, NO, 0);
view.layer.render(inContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
var image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
newLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
newLayer = nil
var imageRef: CGImageRef? = image?.cgImage.cropping(to: rectToCrop)
var croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: imgVPhoto.image.scale, orientation: imgVPhoto.image.imageOrientation)
CGImageRelease(imageRef)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are displaying the image in a UIImageView, you can use the mask property.

You need to make a UIImage out of the path:

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    func asMaskImage(fillColor:UIColor = UIColor.black) -> UIImage
    {
        // Make a graphics context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context!.setFillColor(fillColor.cgColor)

        // and fill it!
        self.fill()

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image!
     }
}
```

Then you use that as the mask:

```
myImageView.image = image
myImageView.mask = UIImageView(image: shape.asMaskImage())
```

Comment: It says `Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage' to type 'UIView?'`

Comment: Sorry - I had simplified some other code. It needs to be put it into a UIImageView. See edit.

Comment: But that isn't what he asked. He asked how to mask a UIImage, not a UIImageView.